# Why i can not set style dynamically from method in Typescript

Tags: typescript, binding, styles

I am trying to set style of rows in a table using a method in the `.ts` file and i get the following error:

```
> IndexComponent.html:16 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting
> object 'cursor:pointer'
>     at KeyValueDiffers.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.KeyValueDiffers.find
> (core.js:16533)
>     at NgStyle.set [as ngStyle] (common.js:3816)
>     at updateProp (core.js:18743)
>     at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:18494)
>     at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:19801)
>     at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:19763)
>     at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:20397)
>     at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:20357)
>     at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (IndexComponent.html:16)
>     at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:20349)
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>

      <tr [ngStyle]="setStyle(item)" (mousedown)="onSelectionChanged(item)" *ngFor="let item of viewComputers">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.username}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**TS**

```
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  public viewComputers:Computer[]=null;
  protected SelectedComputer:Computer=null;

  onSelectionChanged(data:Computer){
    this.SelectedComputer=data;
  }

  public setStyle(value:Computer):string{

    var style="cursor:pointer";
    if(this.SelectedComputer==null ||!(this.SelectedComputer.id==value.id) ){
      console.log(style);
      return style;
    }
    return style+";background-color: #6699ff";
  }

}
```

As you can see if there is no selection on the table (didn't place the logic here) or if the current row is not selected i want to style, otherwise i want the specific one.

Comment: `ngStyle` directive is throwing exception it wants to interpret the value that you have set as a differ. To set raw style you need to bind to `style` instead of `ngstyle` or wrapp it in quotes

Comment: Ok i bound `style` instead of `ngStyle` and now the table is rendered but the coloring when pressed still not working ; i get warnings on each row: `core.js:11407 WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value cursor:pointer (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngStyle expects object but not string https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

```
@Input()
ngStyle: { [klass: string]: any; }
```

The code change

```
  public setStyle(value:Computer):any{

    let style: any ={'cursor': 'pointer'};
    if(this.SelectedComputer==null ||!(this.SelectedComputer.id==value.id) ){
      console.log(style);
      return style;
    }
    return {...style, 'background-color' : '#6699ff' };
  }
```